# Communication Between 2 Databases

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, triggers, communication

I have 2 databases and want to implement triggers on table update of database1 to do do some updates on database2's tables.

**Example**:
db1 has a table 1t1 
db2 has a table 2t1 
on inserting  a touple into 1t1 i want to insert corresponding touple into 2t1

As of now Im using postgresql, but I dont mind switching to other free databases.

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suggest to use database link to establish a connection between two remote DB.

Take a look to this page:

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/contrib-dblink-connect.html

There is also a good tutorial here:

http://www.postgresonline.com/journal/archives/44-Using-DbLink-to-access-other-PostgreSQL-Databases-and-Servers.html

bye,
Andrea

Comment: After some digging I found out that this does not solve the problem completely . I want to do exactly what a trigger does but between 2 databases

Comment: Not sure about the syntax but try to insert into your Trigger code something like that (updating local table, the one with trigger, getting a value from remote table): UPDATE Table1 SET value FROM dblink('dbname=db2', 'SELECT * FROM table2 WHERE id = ' || NEW.cid) WHERE id = NEW.cid;

Answer (score 2):

If you could replace databases with schemas everything becomes easy.
Possibility of such replacement depends on why you have chosen databases as organisational units.

Comment: Im doing it as a course project in which I use data from university database and build another on my own. Updates in university database should reflect in my database also. For now I'm simulating the university database by creating it myself.

Comment: I see, you had no choice. In this case the Andrea's answer is the way to go. OTOH though I'm not really sure you'll have enough permissions to manupuliate the source DB (the University's one), but that's a matter of policy and negotiations I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

Postgresql 9.1 has a new feature called "foreign table":

http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/sql-createforeigntable.html

Does that help maybe?

Comment: that would have been useful..but I have version 8.4 installed ...The feature is not available in 8.4
But I have a doubt regarding th foreign table .Will the updates occur automatically? (will the changes in the original table reflect in the foreign table)

Comment: I don't think there is any need for an original table, plus a foreign table. This is no synchronization tool. You just have a foreign table, and everything you do with it happens remotely. What about installing PG 9.1 on your server?

Comment: Ya got ur point...I use ubuntu and generally prefer to install stuff from standard repositories ...8.4 is latest version available in the repos..Anyways dblink does the job perfectly.